# Code::Blocks подсветка кода в defined

Tags: c++, c, ide, codeblocks

По отзывам некоторых жителей этого ресурса, установил посмотреть `Code::Block`.

Никак не пойму, как бороться с подсветкой между `ifdef`?
Соответственно там серый текст, независимо от того что объявлено, а что нет.. это крайне не удобно.

пример на котором такая картина:

`libbuild.h`:

```
#if ( \
        defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(_Windows) || \
        defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WIN64__) || \
        defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__))

#   define OS_WIN 1
#endif
```

`test.c`

```
#include "libbuild.h"

    #if defined(OS_WIN)

    static int aaa(int i) { return (i + 1); }

    #else

    static long aaa(long i) { return (i + 1); }

    #endif
```

при этом подсвечен всегда код `long aaa(..)`.
Собирается естественно все правильно, а вот смотреть затруднительно.
Сборка при этом проходит под **WIN32**.

вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть решение?

Comment: Картинки здесь были бы более чем уместны.

Comment: Специально попробовал в `CodeBlocks`. Всё нормально отображает. У Вас ```OS_WIN``` объявлен будет при сборке на windows, поэтому всегда будет только один вариант подсвечен (если объявлен хоть один из макросов в условии). Под линуксом будет подсвечен другой. Ради эксперимента, попробуйте закомментировать ```#define OS_WIN 1```, изменится ли ветка?

Comment: @Croessmah, нет ветка не изменилась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подсветка дефайнов зависит от двух вещей:

1. От настроек в секции Settings - Editor - General Settings - C/C++ Editor Settings:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. От используемой темы оформления. В дефолтной теме это выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая тема имеет настройку для элементов в 2-х состояниях: активном и неактивном. Возможно, в используемой вами теме неудачно подобраны цвета для неактивного состояния, а возможно у вас не стоят галочки, как на первом скриншоте.

Но есть один важный момент: для раскраски синтаксиса текущая версия C:B не учитывает дефайны в инклудах. Воспринимаются только те дефайны, которые объявлены в этом же файле или в настройках проекта (Build Options - Compiler Settings - #defines).

Comment: Все темы и настройки по умолчанию. Сделал так же, галочка не стояла только на `include host platform defines`. Пересобрал, изменений не наступило, к сожалению. Возможно надо создавать проект заново при изменении глоб. настроек ? или как то его обновить..

Comment: @NewView А, понял в чём дело. Для раскраски синтаксиса C:B воспринимает только дефайны в пределах одного файла. Если дефайн находится в заголовочнике, то подсветка, действительно, реверсируется и подсвечивается не то, что на самом деле будет компилироваться. Я же, отвечая на вопрос, думал что у вас код вообще подсвечивается одинаково, в обоих ветках дефайна, а проблема оказывается в другом.

Comment: @NewView Соответственно, все что можно посоветовать в этом случае - отключить подсветку неактивной (по мнению С:B) ветки, сняв галочки, которые установлены на первом скриншоте. Тогда все ветки будут подсвечиваться нормально и ни одна из них не будет затемнена.

Comment: :) вероятно так, спасибо за ответ, я так понял что решения нет.. однако :(  Про общую то подсветку понятно, надеялся что есть способ исправить не выключая, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Допишите в свой ответ, и я отмечу как верный